# Events like Keydown & Keypress don't work after adding OpenTK.Control?

Tags: c#, opentk

I am creating a winform app in VS using C#. The following works fine but after adding OpenTK.GLControl in nutget these keyboard events don't work anymore both for the GLControl and the form itself. Does anymore know why and how to fix it? Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you add `protected override OnKeyDown() { MessageBox.Show("Test"); }`, does that get called at all? Also, does setting [`KeyPreview`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to true for the form change anything?

Comment: Thanks Mattew. It works but I just realized the OpenTK.Glcontrol I found on nutget is for .net framework only while I need .net core one. So I just found one on github. But this keyboard event issue still exist even after trying the methods you mentioned. Do you know any potential reasons that might cause this? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I can't think what could cause this.